# How can I access XML nodes of an xml list AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

The class example:

```
package {

    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class XmlLoader extends EventDispatcher{

        private var _xmlList:XMLList;

        public function XmlLoader(xmlPath:String){
            var xmlUrlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlPath);
            var xmlUrlLoader:URLLoader =  new URLLoader(xmlUrlRequest);
            xmlUrlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
        }

        private function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void{
            e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
            var xml:XML = new XML(e.currentTarget.data);
            this._xmlList = xml.*;
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
        }

        public function getXmlList():XMLList{
            return this._xmlList;
        }

    }
}
```

An example of the class use would be:

```
var menuXmlList:XmlLoader = new XmlLoader("pt/menu.xml");
menuXmlList.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, printList);

function printList(e:Event):void{
    trace(e.currentTarget.getXmlList());
}
```

This will print out the content of the xml file.
How can I access the nodes of the xmlList outside the class?

Comment: I do not understand your problem. What exactly is wrong? you get errors or you do know know how to access nodes ?

Comment: Well the problem is after instantiate the class and call the method getData I get this error:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null

Comment: I suppose that the problem is the variable that i'm returning, it's empty right?

Comment: the problem is that you are calling the getXmlList() right away, which the xml was not yet loaded and _xmlList instantiated. Listen for XMLLoader Event.COMPLETE and only then call your code var myList:XMMList = test.getXmlList();
myList.firstNode.secondNode.text()[0];

Comment: I have done this at main timeline:

var menuXmlList:XmlLoader = new XmlLoader("pt/menu.xml");
var list:XMLList;
menuXmlList.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, assignData);

function assignData(e:Event):void{
 list = e.currentTarget.xmlList;
}

trace(list.person.name.text()[0]);

Without success!

Comment: Can toy please tell what is wrong now? ...same error or nothing to console ? Can you maybe update the question and make it more clear to understand what is the problem, so maybe others will be able to help.

Comment: The above example will print the xml content... instead print the content I want to access the nodes of the list. How can it be done?

Thank you Adrian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify a little the loader
     public class XmlLoader extends EventDispatcher{

```
        private var _xml:XML;

        public function XmlLoader(xmlPath:String){
            var xmlUrlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlPath);
            var xmlUrlLoader:URLLoader =  new URLLoader(xmlUrlRequest);
            xmlUrlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
        }

        private function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void{
            e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
            _xml = new XML(e.currentTarget.data);
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
        }

        public function getXml():XML{
            return this._xml;
        }

    }
}
```

I will then access the nodes like this.

```
var menuXmlList:XmlLoader = new XmlLoader("pt/menu.xml");
menuXmlList.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, printList);

function printList(e:Event):void{
    var myXML:XML = (e.currentTarget.getXml());

    var children:XMLList = myXML.children();
    var child:XML;

    for each(child in children)
    {
         trace("Node name: "+child.name()+" -- value: "+String(node));
    }

    // for and xml like
    // <root>
    //     <node1>
    //           <subnode>abc</subnode>
    //           <subnode>def</subnode>
    //           <subnode>ghi</subnode>
    //     </node1>
    //     <node2>
    //           <subnode>123</subnode>
    //           <subnode>456</subnode>
    //           <subnode>789</subnode>
    //     </node2>
    // </root>
    //
    // to access all subnodes inside node 2 use
    //
    // var list:XMLList = xml.node2.subnode;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Adrian, I believe I wanted something like this:

I returned an XML instead XMLList.
Now I can access the xml structure like so:

function printList(e:Event):void{
 var list:XML = new XML(e.currentTarget.getXmlList());
 trace(list.person.name.text()[0]);
}

What you think?

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. That should be correct but please be careful when calling content like this since, and consider what result you should have in the case list.person.name or list.person is null :). I suggest a try=catch in there to avoid future issues.

Comment: thank you. How can I access the myXML outside the function printList?

Comment: The all purpose of the class is to use the returned xml object without calling an extra function so is there a way to assign the value of the returned method to a variable that can be used everywhere?